# Retrieve content from PubNub messages

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, pubnub

I can successfully send and receive messages with PubNub, the problem comes when i try to display content from a message and load it a `UITableViewCell`'s `UITextView`.

The `Second TEST LOG` writes out the whole message, that i send from my iPhone (i've already tried it with the Dev Console), but after this the app crashes.

```
[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I know there is something wrong with a dictionary, but i can't figure it out. I'm using only one `NSDictionary` for the message i send via PubNub and it "arrives" to the console, therefore I think it works properly. As you can see in the code i've tried some variations, but without any success.

**UPDATE**

It's working if i send NSString instead of NSDictionary.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myIncomeMessage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *messageFromDict;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *twoChannels;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *messagePbnb;
//@property (nonatomic, strong) PNMessage *messageNew;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PNChannel *channel_2 = [PNChannel channelWithName:current.username shouldObservePresence:NO];
    PNChannel *channel_1 = [PNChannel channelWithName:self.messageRecipient shouldObservePresence:NO];

    [PubNub subscribeOnChannels:self.twoChannels];

    [PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:channel_1 from:nil to:nil limit:100 reverseHistory:YES];
    [PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:channel_2 from:nil to:nil limit:100 reverseHistory:YES];

    [[PNObservationCenter defaultCenter] addMessageReceiveObserver:self withBlock:^(PNMessage *message) {
        NSLog(@"OBSERVER: Channel: %@, Message: %@", message.channel.name, message.message);
        NSLog(@"Sample TEST LOG %@", message.message);

        self.myIncomeMessage = message.message;
        NSLog(@"Second TEST LOG %@", self.myIncomeMessage);
   //   self.messageFromDict = [NSString stringWithFormat:keyMessage, self.messagePbnb];
   //   self.messageFromDict = [NSString stringWithFormat:keyMessage, message];
    }];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(reloadTable) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [self setupUIForInput];

}


- (IBAction) inputContent {

    NSString *messageContent = self.textView.text;

    PNChannel *channel_1 = [PNChannel channelWithName:self.messageRecipient shouldObservePresence:NO];
    PNChannel *channel_2 = [PNChannel channelWithName:senderUser.username shouldObservePresence:NO];

    self.twoChannels = @[channel_1,channel_2];

    [PubNub subscribeOnChannels: self.twoChannels];

    self.messagePbnb = @{ @"keyMessage": messageContent, @"keySenderUser": self.senderUser.username, @"keyRecieverChannel": self.messageRecipient} ;

    [PubNub sendMessage: self.messagePbnb toChannel:channel_1];
    [PubNub sendMessage: self.messagePbnb toChannel:channel_2];
    [self.textView resignFirstResponder];
    [self reloadInputViews];

}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 10;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    OutputTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellThree"];

    cell.textOutput.text = self.myIncomeMessage;

-(void)reloadTable{
    [tableViewThree reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Which line specifically is the exception occurring on?

Comment: @Dima i couldn't investigate it. After the crash i didn't get red marked errors and the Xcode doesn't "drop" me back to the view controller and shows which line is wrong.

Comment: If you shoot us an email to support@pubnub.com with a complete log attachment of where the crash happens, we're happy to help!

Comment: Thank you @Geremy! I already have an open ticket at PubNub support, but the last answer i got was a customer survey yesterday, therefore i found it better to ask an exact programming question here. I know your smallest problem is bigger than some basic dummy questions from trial users, so i don't wanna harass the support. It would be enough for me if you can post some code about how would you retrieve the keys from a PubNub message that was sent in a dictionary form like `self.messagePbnb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@sabin, here is an example, using an observer -- you could do a similar thing via a delegate:

```
[[PNObservationCenter defaultCenter] addMessageReceiveObserver:self
                                                     withBlock:^(PNMessage *message) {

     id messageData = message.message;
     if ([messageData isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

     NSString *messageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"foo: %@, and bar: <%@>",
             [(NSDictionary *)messageData valueForKey:@"foo"],
             [(NSDictionary *)messageData valueForKey:@"bar"]];
     }
 }];
```

If you then published this from the Web Console (pubnub.com/console):

```
{"foo":"hey", "bar":"you!"}
```

You would be able to render a string from the above code (via messageString) that looked like this:

```
foo: hey, and bar: you!
```

Let me know if that helped!

Comment: Great, it's working perfectly! Thank you! I've spent my whole week with PubNub and now as i better understand it i see that it's simply amazing and very rational. Before i started coding this function i believed it will a nightmare, but it's less than 8 lines of code what is incredible.